# draggable() - preventing dragging element outside window

Tags: jquery

how can you prevent the user to drag the element outside the window?

```
elm.css({
        top : $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() - elm.height()) / 2+'px',
        left : ($(window).width() - elm.width()) / 2+'px'
    })
    .draggable({
        handle : tr_top
    });
```

Comment: The containment option? `.draggable({ containment: 'parent' })`. Check out [the documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [containment](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) option:

```
elm.draggable({
    handle: tr_top,
    containment: "window"
});
```

Comment: +1 .draggable({ containment: 'window' }); worked for me to have only [in the whole window area]